# USB-C C2C (XN005-56) as 5V power supply

Tags: power-supply, usb-c

I am trying to to fix this 5V USB-C board to also work with USB-C to USB-C cables.
Right now it works only with a USB-A to USB-C cable. It should output 5 V on the big pads to the right. In the picture you see the same board twice. The second one is to show the backside. Unfortunately I don't have the schematics for this thing. It was an Ali-express purchase. But everything should be in the picture as there are no layers sandwiched in the PCB.

I did this fix to some other board (JRC-B008) [JRC-B008 for USB-C microcontroller power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595590/jrc-b008-for-usb-c-microcontroller-power-supply) and it worked. I am hoping for a an equally creative fix to this board.

But for the board in the picture I don't really know what to do. The two resistors R1 and R2 are 55.6kΩ resistors. But I am happy to change them if needed.
[image: XN005-56 USB-C 5 Volt board]
I tried to reverse engineer the PCB.[image: schematics of the board XN005-56]

Comment: Need a drawn pin out or schematic, can you reverse engineer the PCB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer I answer my own questions. But a creative solution to fix this thing was found.

A friend found a solution which I then executed. This fix is presented in the picture. The two previous resistors on R1 and R2 are removed.
I then scratched away the solder mask to expose copper where the R1 silk screen was. This new exposed copper area is used to pull down the CC line (instead of pulling it up). And the pad for the non existent capacitor (C1) was used to pull down the other CC line. The two new resistors are 5.1kΩ.

The board now delivers 5V between the big V and G pads, shown in the question, when connected USB-C to USB-C.

[image: fixed XN005-56 board with two new pull down resistors on CC lines]